# How to solve the following probability problem

Tags: combinatorics

Today I had an exam: The professor asked this puzzling question which I cannot solve even afterwards:

1 coin is thrown three times. There are two variables, X & Y.

If the first throw equals tail, X = 0, if the first throw equals head, X = 1.
Y counts the number of heads..

He gave us this table
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
X\backslash Y & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
0 & & &\\ \hline
1 &  & &\\ \hline
\end{array}

We should calculate the joint probability function and determine if X and Y are independent or not.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

The uppermost left corner was written as such. I guess it means that the first row are the values of Y and the first column are the values of X.

Comment: Do you mean a die or a coin?  If you are tossing a fair coin three times....well, then there are only $8$ possible outcomes.  Just list all of them.  As to dependence...well, if $X=1$ could $Y=0$?

Comment: @lulu I meant coin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user @lulu I guess the solution is:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
X\backslash Y & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
0 & 0.125& 0.25& 0.125 & 0\\ \hline
1 & 0  & 0.125 & 0.25 & 0.125\\ \hline
\end{array}